# Processing an entire SQL table via JDBC by streaming or batching on a constrained environment

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-flink, spark-streaming, flink-streaming

I am trying to set up a pipeline for processing entire SQL tables one by one with the initial ingestion happening through JDBC. I need to be able to use higher-level processing capabilities such as the ones available in Apache Spark or Flink and would like to use any existing capabilities rather than having to write my own, although it could be an inevitability. I need to be able to execute this pipeline on a constrained setup (potentially a single laptop). Please note that I am not talking about capturing or ingesting CDC here, I just want to batch process an existing table in a way that would not OOM a single machine.

As a trivial example, I have a table in SQL Server that's 500GB. I want to break it down into smaller chunks that would fit into the 16GB-32GB of available memory in a recently modern laptop, apply a transformation function to each of the rows and then forward them into a sink.

Some of the available solutions that seem close to doing what I need:

1. Apache Spark partitioned reads:

```
 spark.read.format("jdbc").
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("url", url)
      .option("partitionColumn", id)
      .option("lowerBound", min)
      .option("upperBound", max)
      .option("numPartitions", 10)
      .option("fetchsize",1000)
      .option("dbtable", query)
      .option("user", "username")
      .option("password", "password")
      .load()
```

It looks like I can even `repartition` the datasets further after the initial read.
Problem is, in a local execution mode I expect the entire table to be partitioned across multiple CPU cores which will all try to load their respective chunk into memory, OOMing the whole business.

- Is there a way to throttle the reading jobs so that only as many execute as can fit in memory? Can I force jobs to run sequentually?
- Could I perhaps partition the table into much smaller chunks, many more than there are cores, causing only a small amount to be processed at once? Wouldn't that hamper everything with endless task scheduling etc?
- If I wanted to write my own source for streaming into Spark, would that alleviate my memory woes? Does something like [this](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/Jdbc2S) help me?
- Does Spark's memory management kick into play here at all? Why does it need to load the entire partition into memory at once during the read?

2. I looked at Apache Flink as an alternative as the streaming model is perhaps a little more appropriate here. Here's what it offers in terms of JDBC:

```
JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
     .setDrivername("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
     .setDBUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/log_db")
     .setUsername("username")
     .setPassword("password")
     .setQuery("select id, something from SOMETHING")
     .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
     .finish()
```

However, it seems like this is also designed for batch processing and still attempts to load everything into memory.

- How would I go about wrangling Flink to stream micro-batches of SQL data for processing?
- Could I potentially write my own streaming source that wraps the JDBC input format?
- Is it safe to assume that OOMs do not happen with Flink unless some state/accumulators become too big?

I also saw that Kafka has JDBC connectors but it looks like it is not really possible to run it locally (i.e. same JVM) like the other streaming frameworks. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's true that with Flink, input formats are only intended to be used for batch processing, but that shouldn't be a problem. Flink does batch processing one event at-a-time, without loading everything into memory. I think what you want should just work.